# Testflight Error : This invitation has been revoked or is invalid please request a new invite from the developer

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

This issue is happening for Internal Testing

Steps that led to this issue -

1. User had installed the app through Testflight previously.
2. User Factory Reset the phone and updated iOS and reinstalled Testflight.
3. `First Issue` Testflight did not show the app anymore. Clicking on the Testflight link from the invitation email from the past gives the error `Testflight the invitation has already been redeemed`
4. First Issue was Resolved by removing and re-adding the user from '[Users and Access](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users)' inside Appstore Connect.
5. Added user as Tester again in Testflight Internal Testing Group, Resent the invitation.
6. `Second Issue` When the user clicks on the NEW invitation email for testing, getting error `This invitation has been revoked or is invalid please request a new invite from the developer`

Here is the screenshot -
[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this? As specifed above, we have already tried sending invite again as error asks for that,but doesn't help.

PS: Have gone through other remotely similar ques from stackoverflow, Apple dev. already. Did not help as steps / reasons leading to error were different.

Comment: Same issue with iPads running iPadOS 16.1.1 Any workaround or update from Apple?

Comment: I've the same problem.. any solution by now?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this first you have to go to appStoreConnect in testflight and check if your user is inside 'Pruebas internas' and 'Pruebas externas', so eliminate from both. After bellow 'Información General' look for 'All testers'  and eliminate completely your user from the testers. Then add your user inside 'Pruebas internas'. This work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I had logged in to TestFlight with another (e.g. sml_1@exmaple.com) account and redeemed the code with a different account (sml_2@exmaple.com ). So, it was failing. Make sure you are inviting the correct user.