# Couldn't redeem Testflight invitation code

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

We are using Testflight for deploying our iOS app. I was using Testflight. In between that, I had to do a factory reset to get VPN access for my mobile. After getting VPN access and setting up my mobile, I downloaded and installed Testflight.

It asked for Redeem code, But I was already there in the Testflight Internal tester's group in Appstore connect website of my application. It stated that 'You have Installed a version'.

Then I re-invited myself from the Appstore connect and used the redeem code that i received in mail. It threw a alert 'This invitation has been revoked or is invalid. Request a new invitation from the developer'. PFA.

I then removed and re-added my name from the internal tester group, Removed and re-added the access for my application, nothing worked. I made sure that I have been using the correct Apple id through out the process.

I saw another article in stack overflow similar to that of my case. But it doesn't work in my case.

[Testflight Error : This invitation has been revoked or is invalid please request a new invite from the developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74258986/testflight-error-this-invitation-has-been-revoked-or-is-invalid-please-request)

Thanks in advance.

I re-invited myself from the Appstore connect and used the redeem code that i received in mail. It threw a alert 'This invitation has been revoked or is invalid. Request a new invitation from the developer'. PFA.

I then removed and re-added my name from the internal tester group, Removed and re-added the access for my application, nothing worked. I made sure that I have been using the correct Apple id through out the process. But i could not get my application on testflight to install.

Comment: This is probably the wrong place, contact Support or sometimes you can get Apple people on the Dev forums